# Google Search Engine - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Would it be possible to make a google search engine in Xcode, cocoa? If so, how? I want the user to type in a phrase in a textfield called inputBox, and the button to be sendButton. When the button is pressed it will open your default browser to the searched phrase.

Thanks,

KeViN

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See [`-[NSWorkspace openURL:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURL:) and [`-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:).

Also, that isn't what is usually called a "search engine." That is a form that sends a request to Google.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Evidence: [It's been done.](http://wafflesoftware.net/monocle/)

Of course, that needn't stop you from implementing your own as a learning project.

Also, what Chuck said about your use of the term “search engine”.